# Is there a shorthand boolean check for an enum case with associated value?

Tags: swift, enums, pattern-matching, equality

I have this code snippet:

```
if case .voice = mode { 
    return true 
} else { 
    return false 
}
```

Is there a shorthand version maybe? For example:

`.voice == mode ? true : false`

mode is an enum with associated value:

```
enum Mode { 
    case `default`
    case voice(VoiceMode) 
}
```

Comment: I assume `Mode` is simplified here but if not you can declare it to conform to `Equatable` and simply write `mode != .default`

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in method for checking enum case equality without also checking the equality of the associated values. In case your enum conforms to `Equatable`, you can use the equality operator to compare two enum values, however, you still couldn't do `mode == Mode.voice`, since `Mode.voice` isn't valid without a `VoiceMode` associated value.

You can define a computed property on the enum that only compares the cases though, not their associated values.

```
enum Mode {
    case `default`
    case voice(VoiceMode)
    
    var isVoice: Bool {
        if case .voice = self {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```